# Return from a gpio event

Tags: python, return, return-value, gpio

Finally I was able to fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970576/pyaudio-record-when-pushing-a-button) with a program that uses `gpio.add_event_detect`, but when I get the audio file I need to send it to anothe function and get text that that function return. This is my script

```
while auto_recognition==False:
    import RPi.GPIO as gpio
    from manual_recorder import Recorder
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

    gpio.setup(4, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)

    def rising(channel):
        global recfile
        gpio.remove_event_detect(4)
        print 'Button up'
        gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.FALLING, callback=falling, bouncetime=10)
        recfile.stop_recording()
        recfile.close()
        print stt.stt_google_wav(filename, profile.language)

    def falling(channel):
        global recfile
        gpio.remove_event_detect(4)
        print 'Button down'
        gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.RISING, callback=rising, bouncetime=10)
        rec = Recorder(channels=1)
        recfile = rec.open(filename, 'wb') 
        recfile.start_recording()

    filename='output_'+str(int(time.time()))+'.wav'
    gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.FALLING, callback=falling, bouncetime=10)

    gpio.cleanup()
```

I need rising to return the last line, what's now printed. I ve tried with `return stt.stt_google_wav(filename, profile.language)`and then `print gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.FALLING, callback=falling, bouncetime=10)` but it does not work. How can I do it?